# How to create a Mountain Lion DMG image and load it into VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, iso-image, osx-mountain-lion

Basically, I just need to make a full copy of the Mountain Lion installer, but I have no flash, or any other removable medium available.

Is it just possible to clone the system and mount the .dmg file on to virtualbox and install from there?

Comment: Some people are having trouble with VB and ML: https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=51139. Maybe you could attach an external USB disk to your Mac (a disk with a small partition (~15 GB) would be great), restart your Mac, hold down the Command and the R keys and install ML on the external partition (see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4718). Then you could convert the external partition to DMG with Disk Utility and try somehow to import it to VB.